# Python - counting times a server receives request from client?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I'm playing around with python lately and trying to learn how to build a python server, using TCP connections.

I have this code that runs a server...

```
import socket
from threading import *
import datetime
import time


serversocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
host = "localhost"
port = 8000
print (host)
print (port)

serversocket.bind((host, port))

class client(Thread):

    def __init__(self, socket, address):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.sock = socket
        self.addr = address
        self.start()


    def run(self):

        while 1:

            st = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.time()).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
            #cName  =
            print(self.sock.recv(1024).decode()+' sent @ '+ st + ':' , self.sock.recv(1024).decode())

            self.sock.send(b'Processing!')





serversocket.listen(5)
print ('server started and listening')
while 1:
    clientsocket, address = serversocket.accept()
    client(clientsocket, address)
```

And two of these client.py

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
host ="localhost"
port =8000
cName = 'client 2' # or client 1
s.connect((host,port))

def ts(str):
   s.sendall(cName.encode())
   s.send('e'.encode())
   data = ''
   data = s.recv(1024).decode()
   print (data)

while 2:
   r = input('enter')
   ts(s)

s.close ()
```

I want to know how to allow the server to count and keep track of how many times it recieves a message from both client 1 and client 2.

For example, if server starts at count of 0 (e.g. `count = 0)`. And each time client 1 or client 2 sends back a message or in this case, hits enter, the count will go up (`count += 1`). If I call for a `print(count)`, the output should be `1`.

Thanks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can create a global variable (say `count=0`) in your first script (server script) and keep incrementing the value every time you receive the message from a client.

So your run method can become,

```
def run(self):
        global count
        while 1:

            st = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.time()).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
            #cName  =
            print(self.sock.recv(1024).decode()+' sent @ '+ st + ':' , self.sock.recv(1024).decode())
            count += 1
            self.sock.send(b'Processing!')
```

If you want the count to be client specific then create a dictionary of counts instead of a single integer and keep incrementing the respective integer on verifying some thing about a client.